# remove a whole line with a specific string followed by an allcaps word

Tags: command-line

I am trying hard to write an expression for a case here but I can not. I use Ultraedit as my text editor, using Perl as my regular expression engine.

here is an example

MSDA

I have a large document with such lines that I want to delete completely, so basically I need to search for any  followed by All Caps acronym or word like that.

Here are samples of the lines I want to delete

INTAFOHR
RPPO

Can you please help ASAP?

Thanks

Sam

Comment: IMHO your question as it stands doesn't state the requirements clearly enough to answer. Please consider adding a fuller sample including both some lines you want to delete AND some lines you want to keep. Also if you have been "trying hard" then summarize what you have tried so far and in what way it doesn't achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using sed and it is very basic question what you are asking.

```
  man sed
```

will give you the clue.

here is the full command for what you are looking for:

```
sed -i '/^[A-Z][A-Z]/d' file
```

Sed checks inside of given file and if there is more than 1 upper case sequentially it will delete the entire line.

I think this is what you have asked, otherwise pls re-formulate the question and be more specific.